# Python: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

Tags: python, urllib, http-status-code-403

Getting this error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/urllib/request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

headers:

```
headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.84 Safari/537.36",
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,/;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
        "Accept-Charset": "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3",
        "Accept-Encoding": "none",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
    }
```

Despite using `User-Agent` in the request's headers, I'm getting this error: `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

My code:

```
import urllib

req = urllib.request.Request(url=url, headers=headers)
urllib.request.urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8")  ##error is coming from this line.
```

NOTE: This code is working with most of the URL.

Comment: HTTP returns 403 when you try to access to a domain you have no authority over. Check if you are allowed to access to the specific url path.

Comment: We can't help you without knowing the URLs.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403

Answer (score 0):

HTTP returns `403 Forbidden` when you try to access to a path you have no authority over. It shouldn't be the problem of the code. Check if you are allowed to access to the url and add required information through `headers` or `cookie` to prove that you have the allowance to access to the path.